# Application works like a charm on emulator while force closes in device in android

Tags: android, sqlite

**This is my dbAdapter class**

```
public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "";
private static final String DB_NAME = "v2v.sqlite";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

private static DBAdapter mDBConnection;

DBAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.lauruss.verb2verbe/databases/";
}

public static synchronized DBAdapter getDBAdapterInstance(Context context) {
    if (mDBConnection == null) {
        mDBConnection = new DBAdapter(context);
    }
    return mDBConnection;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    /*SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;*/
/// New changed code
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput;
    OutputStream myOutPut;
    try {
        myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName =DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myOutPut = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutPut.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutPut.flush();
        myOutPut.close();
        myInput.close();
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);      
    return myDataBase;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

**This is my SQLAccess class**

```
public class SQLiteAccess {

private static SQLiteDatabase db;
static DBAdapter adb = null;

static VerbBean objVB = null;



public static String selectOneWordEnglish(String sql,
        Context mcontext) {
    String objVB = null;
    adb = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(mcontext);
    try {
        adb.createDataBase();

        db = adb.openDataBase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                objVB = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("english"));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return objVB;
}



public static String selectOneValueSQL(String sql,Context mcontext)
{ 
    adb = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(mcontext);
    try {
        adb.createDataBase();

        db = adb.openDataBase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                return c.getColumnName(c.getColumnIndex("SortOrder"));
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
  return ""; 
}

public static int selectCount(String sql, Context mContext)
{   int count = 0;
    adb = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(mContext);
    try {
        adb.createDataBase();

        db = adb.openDataBase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        count = c.getCount();

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
}
db.close();
return count ;
}


public static int insertWithSQL(String sql,Context mContext)
{adb = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(mContext);
try {
    adb.createDataBase();

    db = adb.openDataBase();

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

} catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
    sqlEx.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ioEx) {
    ioEx.printStackTrace();
}
db.close();
    return 0; 

}




public static Vector<VerbBean> selectAllFromDatabase(String sql,Context mContext)
{
    Vector<VerbBean> vecVB = new Vector<VerbBean>();
    VerbBean objVB;
    adb = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(mContext);
    try {
        adb.createDataBase();
        db = adb.openDataBase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        if (c.getCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
                objVB= new VerbBean();
                objVB.setVerbId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("VerbID")));
                objVB.setVerbName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("VerbName")));
                vecVB.addElement(objVB);
                c.moveToNext();
            }   
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        sqlEx.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioEx) {
        ioEx.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.close();
    return vecVB;   
}
```

}

**And this is what the warning is when i install my app in android device (HTC Wildfire)**

```
05-04 12:07:14.033: WARN/System.err(2145): java.io.IOException
05-04 12:07:14.033: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:36)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:571)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DBAdapter.copyDataBase(DBAdapter.java:101)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DBAdapter.createDataBase(DBAdapter.java:45)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-04 12:07:14.043: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
05-04 12:07:14.053: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 12:07:14.053: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-04 12:07:14.053: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
05-04 12:07:14.053: WARN/System.err(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 12:07:14.053: WARN/System.err(2145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 12:07:14.063: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-04 12:07:14.063: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-04 12:07:14.063: WARN/System.err(2145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 12:07:14.143: INFO/Database(2145): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tblVocab
05-04 12:07:14.153: WARN/System.err(2145): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblVocab: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblVocab
05-04 12:07:14.163: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
05-04 12:07:14.163: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
05-04 12:07:14.163: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
05-04 12:07:14.163: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1417)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1387)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.SQLiteAccess.selectCount(SQLiteAccess.java:201)
05-04 12:07:14.173: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DataAccess.getRandomVocab(DataAccess.java:59)
05-04 12:07:14.183: WARN/System.err(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.MainActivity.run(MainActivity.java:171)
05-04 12:07:14.183: WARN/System.err(2145):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
05-04 12:07:14.193: WARN/dalvikvm(2145): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:225)
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DataAccess.getRandomVocab(DataAccess.java:64)
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.MainActivity.run(MainActivity.java:171)
05-04 12:07:14.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2145):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
05-04 12:07:14.213: WARN/ActivityManager(102):   Force finishing activity com.lauruss.verb2verbe/.MainActivity
```

**When i connect device and run for first time, it show's warning as below**

```
05-04 12:38:01.983: WARN/System.err(2857): java.io.IOException
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.readAsset(Native Method)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.access$700(AssetManager.java:36)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream.read(AssetManager.java:571)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DBAdapter.copyDataBase(DBAdapter.java:80)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DBAdapter.createDataBase(DBAdapter.java:45)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
05-04 12:38:01.993: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1065)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2745)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2132)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 12:38:02.003: WARN/System.err(2857):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 12:38:02.013: WARN/System.err(2857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-04 12:38:02.013: WARN/System.err(2857):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-04 12:38:02.013: WARN/System.err(2857):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: error says it clearly..`no such table: tblVocab` either the table/database not copied to device..or table not exists in database...

Comment: the same code of copy database in working in another app of mine, is it because the database size is larget (22mb approx)

Comment: problem also can be like..it takes time to completely copy database to phone..and before its copied..you make the query on table..so check for that..

Comment: see `at com.lauruss.verb2verbe.DBAdapter.copyDataBase(DBAdapter.java:101)`.. io error on 4th line..

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the database extension to .mp3 because android has a size limitation for databases having extension .sqlite. It allows data onl upto 4 MB.

Comment: bt then how to covert that file to database file ??

Comment: no need to convert it. While saving the database, just change the extension. Are you using external db or internal?

Comment: Also, delete your application completely from the device before testing. Sometimes, the changes are not reflected if you make any, and the table which is create newly is not recognised. Try using SQLIte plugin for MOZILLA

Comment: i m not getting your, can provide me the code or ref, how can i save using db or sqlite extension after copy ???

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be you are trying to open the database before it loaded into the application. Always keep these points in mind before using the database...

1. create a lock before creating the database
2. show processing dialog to the user
3. Try with single following path

"/Android/data/packagename/dbname" == For mobile memory

"/sdcard/Android/data/packagename/dbname" == For SdCard